# Getting history of the messages processed by JMS queues in Weblogic

Tags: oracle, queue, jms, weblogic, application-server

I want to see the history of the messages processed by a JMS queue for a durable subscriber. There is only a show message button which shows the current messages.

I searched on the Oracle blog but didn't find any clue to see the history of the messages processed.

Here is the screenshot of the page I am looking at. Is there anybody here who came across this situation where they wanted to see the history of the messages processed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to see already processed transactions on weblogic console but Monitoring tools like DynaTrace helps to see the statistics for past transactions on JMS queues through purepaths.